# IBM worklight 6.2 - how to save files in the app?

Tags: file, save, ibm-mobilefirst

I am now developing Apps using IBM worklight 6.2, and for offline usage, my app need to download all the demo data from the server, may I ask:

how can I save files(like .png, .mp3, .ppt) in the app when online and show for offline usage ? 
can I direct use JSONStore to do so ? or any other local storage method ?
by the way, I need to develop it both in IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution would be to follow the training modules and documentation for JSONStore and use it to store any file you want.

See more information here:

- [Worklight - Working Offline](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_work_offline)
- [JSONStore user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en)

Otherwise, you can implement Cordova File API. But, JSONStore is more built-in...

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: ok....
I just want to know what is the common way to do the file saving....
so, you mean save all the files(like .png, .mp3, .ppt)JSONStore is also working? is it normal practice? what if I encrypt the JSONStore file? will it be slow to load the file ?

Comment: It shouldn't slow it too much; you need to experiment and find what works best for you. No magic solution.