# IBM Worklight- How to copy a file from Xampp

Tags: download, ibm-mobilefirst

There is a file stored on my localhost called doc1.ppt(http://localhost/doc1.ppt).
How can i download the file in the hybrid app using ibm worklight.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display PPT files within a Hybrid application.

Best you can do is to retrieve the file using Cordova File API and store it in the device, and check if Windows Phone provides API to open .PPT files in a PPT viewer app in the device or in a built-in functionality that provides this (which I do not believe there is any).

Comment: How can i download a file(e.g .txt)? because if i use Cordova File API, it will not be a hybrid app since Cordova File API is a native feature.

Comment: Read the Cordova API.

Comment: Apache Cordova API is use to access native feature, i just want to know how to download the file.

Comment: No. Cordova API also provides FileTransfer API which you will need to use in order to download the file and store it in the device, using the Cordova File System API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860943/ibm-worklight-6-2-how-to-save-files-in-the-app

Check this link. Is it possible to save the file?

Comment: Referring to this question/post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860943/ibm-worklight-6-2-how-to-save-files-in-the-app?lq=1
how can I save files(like .png, .mp3, .pdf) in the app.